# How to call PostgreSQL stored procedure from java

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures

I need to call a store procedure from java. My store procedure name is `post_all_values()`. In this i need to pass two arguments. First argument should be null and second should be id.If i execute in postgey sql window its working fine. How to call my stored procedure from java. Please help me. Following is my code. But its not working.

```
final List parameters = new ArrayList();
 parameters.add("id1");
      final String procedureName = "post_all_values";
      CallStoredProcedure.getInstance().call(procedureName, parameters, null);
```

its showing error like

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function post_all_values(character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 8

Please help to correct this code. Give your own code..

Comment: What is a "*postgey sql window*"?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you are calling it with a single varchar argument and it can't find a matching function.

In your text you say it needs two arguments.

Try calling it woth two.